# CDI 1.1 Dispose injected resource Immediate after using

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, cdi, inject

I have a SimpleResource class

```
@Vetoed
public class SimpleResource {
  private String value="TestValue";
  public void open(){
     System.out.println("Open SR method");  
 }  
 public void close(){
   System.out.println("Close SR method");
 }
 public String getValue() {
   return value;
 }  
}
```

Then I've created a Producer Class

```
@Singleton
public class EntityManagerProducer {

 @Produces
 @Default
 @Dependent
 public static SimpleResource createSimpleResource() {
   SimpleResource sr = new SimpleResource();
   System.out.println("Open SR");
   sr.open();
   return sr;
 }

 public static void disposeSimpleResource(@Disposes @Default SimpleResource  simpleResource) {
  System.out.println("Close SR");
  simpleResource.close();
  }
}
```

And than a Singleton Business class

```
@Default
@Singleton
public class InjectConstructor {
 private  String value="init";

 @Inject
 public InjectConstructor(SimpleResource sr){
  value=sr.getValue();
 }

 public String getValue() {
   return value;
 }
}
```

The test method to run

```
 @Test
 public void injectConstructor(){
  Weld weld = new Weld();
  WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
  InjectConstructor inst= container.select(InjectConstructor.class).get();   
  System.out.println("Value= "+inst.getValue());
 }
```

After runnning  test program  I've got such response:

INFO  org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap - WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container STATIC_INSTANCE initialized 
Open SR
Open SR method
Value= TestValue
Close Container
Close SR
Close SR method

The problem is that "SimpleResource" is opend before constructor @Inject  BUT not close after constructor exited.

The question is How to inject "SimpleResource" through Constructor injection and closed Immediate after constructor exited?

Is the only tecnique to do this is using @Observes method?

```
public void watchStartup(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object ctxEvent, SimpleResource sr) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin Couba helped me to solve this problem.

> you could make use of @javax.enterprise.inject.TransientReference. The producer method for SimpleResource is @Dependent so the disposer method should be called when the invocation of the constructor completes.

```
@Inject
public InjectConstructor(@TransientReference SimpleResource sr) {
  value = sr.getValue();
}
```

Thank you very much. It is very ellegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Because you're making `SimpleResource` dependent, its scope is tied to the lifecycle of the parent, as a result its managed like a singleton.  To do what you're looking for, you'd have to make the constructor aware of the bean directly, and perhaps use [Unmanaged](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/Unmanaged.html) to create then destroy an instance.

Comment: I am try to use this tecinique. It use "SimpleResource" constructor but I need use Producer method.

Comment: I can produce SimpleResource by: `CDI.current().select(SimpleResource.class).get();` It uses my Produser method for creation of resource BUT I cannot call @Dispose to destroy it after using